# How to rotate an image by hovering over a different div in css3?

Tags: css

I have one image and 4 different divs.I am trying to rotate that image at different degrees depending on the div that is hovered over. By far, I have only been able to rotate the image by hovering over itself. There is no parent-child relationship. Is what I am trying to do achievable?

**HTML**

```
<div id="line">
<img src="images/Line2.png" id="liner" alt="settings" />
</div>
<div id="d1">
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#d1:hover + #liner {
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg) ;
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

}

Comment: + is for the next sibling. You can't go 'up' using pure css. Consider using jQuery

Comment: @shaunsantacruz @nitish-parab how about `body:has(#d1:hover) #liner`?

Answer (score 1):

The most sane solution is to do this with javascript. BUT if you want to do this purely in CSS3 it is possible. Check out this JSFiddle I put together for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/4NQfj/

The trick is to nest divs and finally nest the image at the deepest level. So for example:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">
        <div id="d3">
            <img id="couldBeAnImage" src="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply adjust the image's transform property by scoping the image on each div's :hover. So to shorten the code in the fiddle I'm basically doing this:

```
#d1:hover #couldBeAnImage { transform: rotate(15deg); }
#d2:hover #couldBeAnImage { transform: rotate(30deg); }
#d3:hover #couldBeAnImage { transform: rotate(45deg); }
```

The reason you'd want to use javascript is because each div needs to be sized and positioned for this trick to work. That's not a problem except for the fact that it's not always realistic to assume you can: a.) do this given your layout and.. b.) deal with the fact that each div and the subsequent image's positions are all relative to each ancestor div.

So that makes it kind of tricky but this is a 100% CSS solution to the problem you were describing. Pretty fun to solve if I don't say so myself :)

**Edit:**

Sure you can do this with javascript too. Here's a fiddle demonstrating a slightly "sloppy" solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/k3t2U/1/

The way you'd do this is by adding mouseover and mouseout events to the divs. In this case the divs can be completely independent from each other:

```
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>
<div id="couldBeAnImage"></div>
```

In my example I used jQuery's .hover() method to add the event handlers. Hover basically let's you do this: .hover(functionToCallOnMouseOver(), functionToCallOnMouseOut())

So I'm still handling the rotation in CSS. I have three classes that represent the different levels of rotation. Then in my mouseOver and mouseOut event handlers I add or remove the classes that specify the various amounts of rotation.

```
$("#d1").hover(function(){
    $("#couldBeAnImage").addClass("rotate");
},function(){
    $("#couldBeAnImage").removeClass("rotate");
});
```

In javascript you could really do this any number of ways. So this is just one example. It's more powerful in the sense that you have more freedom and control over the actual elements. The CSS method is basically a 'trick' and you're extremely limited in how you can specify your markup and styling. In general, I would recommend solving this problem using javascript.

Comment: I did try doing it with javascript initially but it wasnt working for some reason. It was similar to the answer above yours. Would you mind showing me the javascript way as well using the same layout. That would be wonderful. Though im not much of a fan of it, I know its always better using javascript.

Comment: HI Jim,I did everything exactly as you have shown but for some reason, it isnt working. Do you have any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Nitish -- I'd need to see you're code. Could you post it to jsfiddle?

Comment: Dont know whats missing when I do it on my side?

Comment: Hey Nitish -- I can't help you out unless I can see the actual code causing an issue for you. If you're going th javascript route -- you should get up to speed on how to use the web inspector to debug javascript. Check to see if you're getting any errors in the log. Also, since you're using jQuery you will want to make sure you wrap your JS in $(document).ready(function(){ /* You're code here. */ }); to ensure it properly executed once the DOM has completed loading.

Comment: No I have included the js in a separate .js file. Im not sure whats the hindrance as the code works well in the jsfiddle i shared with you, but not on my end here.